# Omniauth::Builder middleware delete rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have an app that uses Omniauth to login to Twitter and Google.

I have a config file that initializes the parameters for omniauth-twitter and omniauth-google-oauth2 gems like so:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :twitter, ID, SECRET,
{
   :use_authorize => 'true',
   :authorize_params => {
   :force_login => 'true',
   }
}
```

end

When I change the parameters and restart the server the changes are not picked up.

I was wondering if this is because the middleware needs to be re-loaded or if there is some other problem related to my rails server.

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: If I try to delete the middleware using:  Rails.configuration.middleware.delete "OmniAuth::Builder",           I get the following message:  `delete': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)

Comment: It's strange ! Because for refresh code, you need restart your server, no need more.

Comment: See also https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/668

Comment: I filed a new issue since that one was closed: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/751

Answer (score -1):

Remove your statement from your **config/initializers/omniauth.rb** file and put it in **application.rb** like so:

```
config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :twitter, ID, SECRET,
{
   :use_authorize => 'true',
   :authorize_params => {
   :force_login => 'true',
   }
}
```

Yes, this sucks but at least it works.